# Double buffering throws exception at high load

Tags: c#, winforms, out-of-memory, doublebuffered

I am testing my windows forms user control. When application load is high (say application takes more than 1 GB), it throws **Out of memory** or **Argument invalid** exceptions.

Here is the code to draw the control with buffer,

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
      if (m_buffer == null || m_Redraw)
      {
           if (m_buffer != null)
               m_buffer.Dispose();
            m_buffer = new Bitmap(Width, Height);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(m_buffer))
            {
                DrawUserControl(g, ClientRectangle);
            }
            m_Redraw= false;                
       }
       e.Graphics.DrawImage(m_buffer, Point.Empty);
       base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Out of memory exception occurs at `e.Graphics.DrawImage(m_buffer, Point.Empty);`

Argument invalid exception occurs at `new Bitmap(Width, Height);`

> Note: Exception occurs only if application load is more that 1 GB (say
>   1.5 GB with 2GB RAM).

Painting control without buffering does not throw any exception but causes flickering effect. Here is code without buffering

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
     this.SuspendLayout();
     DrawUserControl(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle);
     this.ResumeLayout();
     base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

I want my control to render without flickering under high load. I don't want the application to break due to my control. Please share your suggestions

**Edit related to buffering:**

1) Buffer image will not be created during all paint events. It will be created during the first time and if control needs to be repainted. Otherwise, existing buffer image will be drawn on the control. This avoids unwanted repainting of the control

2) If control needs to be repainted, a new bitmap will be used because size of the existing buffer image and current size of the control may vary. Even if I use existing image, **Argument is not valid** exception thrown

**Tried using BufferedGraphicsContext**

As per @taffer's answer, I tried using `BufferedGraphicsContext`. It also throws **Out of memory exception**. I'm posting the stack trace below

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Not enough storage
>   is available to process this command
>          at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.CreateCompatibleDIB(IntPtr hdc,
>   IntPtr hpal, Int32 ulWidth, Int32 ulHeight, IntPtr& ppvBits)
>
> at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.CreateBuffer(IntPtr src,
>   Int32 offsetX, Int32 offsetY, Int32 width, Int32 height)
>
> at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.AllocBuffer(Graphics
>   targetGraphics, IntPtr targetDC, Rectangle targetRectangle)
>
> at
>   System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.AllocBufferInTempManager(Graphics
>   targetGraphics, IntPtr targetDC, Rectangle targetRectangle)
>       at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.Allocate(Graphics targetGraphics, Rectangle targetRectangle)

Comment: Try avoid loading all at once ? Load them part by part and combine with splash screen ?

Comment: You don't need to Dispose and recreate the buffer every time you paint. Just clear it.

Comment: creating a bitmap is *expensive*.. and you are doing it, potentially, hundreds of times per second.  Allocate your buffer outside of any high traffic areas.

Comment: If you do that, you need to handle resize events though.

Comment: Also, most controls have a doublebuffer flag you can set in the .ctor via [Control.SetStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Side note: `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` have nothing to do with painting. Painting your control should never trigger a `LayoutEvent`, otherwise your control will be very slow. You should delete those lines.

Comment: @Loathing, thanks for the information

Comment: @Blorgbeard, I'm not creating and disposing the buffer during every paint. It will be disposed and created only if there is a need to draw the control otherwise existing image of the control will be drawn. If I clear the buffer image, then resizing will become a problem. I'll edit my question with more details

Comment: Any reason why do you call SuspendLayout/RestoreLayout in OnPaint? OnPaint is not right place to do any layout inside it.

Comment: @Alex, My control uses calculation for rendering and the calculation depends upon location and size of the control along with child controls. It uses 3 child controls and they can be placed in and around the parent. I'm using my own logic for docking child controls.

Comment: The main reason for using suspend/remove layout is to avoid layouting while painting the control. Because my control is a data visualization control and rendering time depends upon the size of data source. It may take upto 5 mins if 10 million records are present in the data source.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, why do you call `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` in `OnPaint`? It is required only if a container control (eg. Panel) contains child controls with docking/alignments and you want to prevent automatic re-alignments when the container is resized in more than one steps.

Secondly, there are many better built-in ways for double-buffering.

**Option 1:**

For `Form`s, `Panel`s and other usual controls in most cases it is enough to set the `DoubleBuffered` property. It is protected so you should create a derived class:

```
public class DoubleBufferedPanel : Panel
{
    public DoubleBufferedPanel()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

Call `SetStyle`:

```
public class DoubleBufferedPanel : Panel
{
    public DoubleBufferedPanel()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }
}
```

**Option 3:**

There are some cases when the options above cannot be used (for example, fading animations of Windows cannot be used with double buffering). Here you can use the `BufferedGraphics` class in `OnPaint`:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // creating a buffered context
    using (BufferedGraphicsContext context = new BufferedGraphicsContext())
    {
        // creating a buffer for the original Graphics
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, Control.ClientSize);
        using (BufferedGraphics bg = context.Allocate(e.Graphics, rect))
        {
            using (PaintEventArgs be = new PaintEventArgs(bg.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle))
            {
                // Draw your control here onto the buffer (applied to your post)
                DrawUserControl(be.Graphics, rect);
                base.OnPaint(be);
            }

            // copying the buffer onto the original Graphics
            bg.Render(e.Graphics);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, Options 1 and 2 will not be useful because my control is derived from Control class. I'll try option 3

Comment: Option 3 also throws exception, I'll add the details in my question